# Symfony forms - "repeat" field and multi errors mapping

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I've got a little problem with my form's errors mapping:

I've a "repeat" field to confirm an email. This one can produce two different errors:

1. The first one triggered if both email are not matching.
2. The second one triggered if the input email already exists in my DB.

I would like to display this first error under the second input and the other under the first input.

I'm displaying my form with the default helper (`form_start()`, `form_widget()` and then `form_end()`).

Applying the following option to my field allow me to display errors under the second input :

```
'error_mapping'  => array(
    '.' => 'second',
),
```

But, is it possible to clarify the "dot", giving an error name or something like that?

Many thank's! :)

Comment: *But, is it possible to clarify the "dot", giving an error name or something like that?* - What do you mean?

Comment: I'm speaking about the "dot" used as a key in the "error_mapping" array. Actually, this dot is matching every inputs. I wonder if it could be possible to specify it.